# more idiomatic way to make a simple correction of returned value

Tags: python, idioms

This code to me looks like in Python there could be a nicer way of doing it:

```
val = some_heavy_foo(slow=True, side_effects=True, bar=lot_of_data)
if val is None:
    val = 0
```

Is there?

A possible use case:

```
total = 0
for lot_of_data in lots_of_data_list:
    val = some_heavy_foo(slow=True, side_effects=True, bar=lot_of_data)
    if val is None:
        val = 0
    total += val
```

I'd like to use `sum()` here, but of course:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific use case:

```
from functools import partial
from operator import is_not
from itertools import ifilter

# Create a callable that only needs bar
f = partial(some_heavy_foo, slow=True, side_effects=True)

# Ignore None values
is_not_none = partial(is_not, None)

# Some return values of f that aren't None
total = sum(ifilter(is_not_none, f(bar=x) for x in lot_of_data))
```

Comment: The amount of parenthesis makes it look dangerously like LISP though.

Comment: Oo, I like! Although, the first partial `f` is not really necessary, except to keep the sum in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you really want.  I've seen that people from the javascript crowd tend to like `or`:

```
val = some_heavy_foo(slow=True, side_effects=True, bar=lot_of_data) or 0
```

as that is a very common javascript idiom.  Of course, this will translate **all** falsy values to `0`.  That's probably fine in this case as usually you shouldn't be writing code where you're not sure if you have an integer or a list or something else ...

Personally, I'm more in favor of saying exactly what you mean (i.e. write it the way you did originally), but that's just my preference.

You could also defer the checking until the next line:

```
val = some_heavy_foo(slow=True, side_effects=True, bar=lot_of_data)
total += 0 if val is None else val
```

but, I'm not convinced that is a whole lot better ...

Answer (score 0):

This is succinct but if you are not used to a functional style, I'm not sure it's a lot better. As in the other answer, this gives you 0 for any "falsy" values, and sums everything.

```
tot = sum(map(lambda x: x if x else 0,
    [some_heavy_foo(slow=True, side_effects=True, bar=data) for data in lots_of_data]))
```